# Is it possible to turn on/off heroku worker from django view?

Tags: python, django, heroku

To start a worker in heroku

```
 $ heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

To stop a worker in heroku

```
 $ heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

Is it possible to stop/start heroku worker from django view ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll need to get setup with [Heroku's Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart). Then in your view you'll want to make calls to their API. They have created a [python library](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.py) to wrap around the API.

The call should be

```
app.processes['worker'].scale(1)
```